# Looking for some guidance on NFC codes and or NDEF

Tags: android, nfc

I have an ACR122 NFC reader that I'm connecting to an Android device via USB. The Android device is running ICS and doesn't have native NFC functionality.

The SDK that comes with the ACR122 comes with a sample app that is fairly dense and very sparsely documented, however, I can see that they are sending messages as APDU hex arrays. I'm new to this, so am somewhat unclear on how these commands actually work and in what circumstances.

Meanwhile, it would appear that there's now something called NDEF, which abstracts the APDU and allows for a much less confusing message exchange (at least as per [this](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/getting-started-nfc-android) tutorial) however, that's only available on NFC enabled devices (or so it would appear)... I'm hoping there's some way to leverage it with the ACR122.

So, my question is:

Does anyone know if I can utilize NDEF with the ACR122's SDK? I'm not trying to do anything complicated, I just want to read and write to the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, NFC classes are part of the ICS SDK, but will always return that no NFC is available.

For the ACR 122, [my experience](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) is purely through [NFC Tools for Java](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools), it might very well contain some interesting parts which can be ported to Android. It also has its own NDEF parse/serialize part.

For an alternative NDEF parse/serialize library, see [here](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android)

Comment: the NFC Tools look very promising. I was expecting to be stuck having to use the lib provided by ACR, but if I can bypass that, then yeah, that looks like it will do the trick. Thanks very much for the info. I may hit you up for a tiny bit more guidance, but I'm +1 ing your answer either way :)